# Purpose of Bokeh custom JS callbacks

Tags: bokeh

This question is may be a bit too general. Why do the JS callbacks exist in Bokeh?
Why would you want to use a CustomJS callback (with our without a Python function) instead of a regular event handler function for a widget?

Here is the guide for the CustomJS callbacks: https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/interaction/callbacks.html#customjs-for-range-update

But why go through that when you can have the same widget and use an event handler function as seen here: [https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/interaction/widgets.html#slider](https://docs.bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/interaction/widgets.html#slider)

In the example at the last link you can make an event handler function run on every change in the input box without getting CustomJS callbacks involved:

```
def my_text_input_handler(attr, old, new):
 print("Previous label: " + old)
 print("Updated label: " + new)

text_input = TextInput(value="default", title="Label:")
text_input.on_change("value", my_text_input_handler)
```

What confuses me is that I feel like you should be able to make an advanced event handler for a widget by simply using the last method without using CustomJS callbacks. 
Many of the examples in the CustomJS guide (first link) deal with interactions with widgets like the slider.

Comment: I believe custom JS callbacks allow for more control/finetuning and they should work in Jupyter notebooks while normal bokeh callbacks do not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use CustomJS callback to have interactions in static html files. And like any language translation tool, the from_py_func method is going to be limited to simple python functions.

Also some object properties are internal to bokehjs and can only be accessed via CustomJS callback like Tool.active